# How to send Outlook meeting invitations without outlook (java, php, etc)

Tags: java, email, events, outlook

I'm trying to build a plugin for our calendar allowing us to send meeting invitations as they are done in Outlook (including accept, maybe decline) via our webserver. At the moment I have no idea how this invitation message is build up and didn't find any clue for this.

Short: What we want:

Create an event in our existing online calendar 
select participants (mail)
send them an invitation allowing them to accept or decline in outlook (as if it had been sent from a normal outlook account)
use the users response to show if he acceppted (therefore we need an imap account).

I hope you can give me a hint how to do this. I'm sure I just used the wrong search terms.

Thanks and happy new year

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is by attaching an .ics file on your emails. Check this [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar#Events_.28VEVENT.29) wikipedia article for more details.

Here's an example of an .ics file you need to attach to your email (Outlook will recognise it as an event):

**meeting.ics**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Meeting invitation
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20150104T123601
UID:20050115T101010/27346262376@mxm.dk
LOCATION:Conference room
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:someone@somewhere.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: So I just attach the meeting.ics to any sent mail or do I need a specific kind of mailtype.

Comment: I tried sending it as a normal attachment over my mail programm but outlook didn't recognize it :(

Comment: @ChristianFelixKazuya The content type of the attached file must be set to 'text/calendar'. Once they click the attached ics file, and accept it, it will be added to the calendar.